¿Cómo puedo acomodar de manera correcta las imágenes del ejemplo usando el atributo position?
Tengo dudas sobre el uso del atributo position: relative y absolute.
Les coloco el código a continuación; necesito realizar la distribución de las imágenes de acuerdo a como les adjunto en las imágenes.
HTML:
    <div class="events__cover">
        <img class="events__image" src="./images/cafe.png" alt="imagen de fondo"/>
        <div class="person" class="person_name_feynman">
                  <p class="person__caption">Joan Feynman</p>
                  <img
                    class="person__image"
                    class="person__image_size_l"
                    src="./images/person_feynman.png"
                    alt="imagen de Feynman"
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="person" class="person_name_burbidge">
                  <p class="person__caption">Margaret Burbidge</p>
                  <img
                    class="person__image"
                    class="person__image_size_s"
                    src="./images/person_burbidge.png"
                    alt="imagen de Burbidge"
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="person" class="person_name_tarter">
                  <p class="person__caption">Jill Tarter</p>
                  <img
                    class="person__image"
                    class="person__image_size_s"
                    src="./images/person_tarter.png"
                    alt="imagen de Tarter"
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="person" class="person_name_mitchel">
                  <p class="person__caption">Maria Mitchel</p>
                  <img
                    class="person__image"
                    class="person__image_size_s"
                    src="./images/person_mitchell.png"
                    alt="imagen de Mitchel"
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="person" class="person_name_cannon">
                  <p class="person__caption">Annie Jump Cannon</p>
                  <img
                    class="person__image"
                    class="person__image_size_s"
                    src="./images/person_cannon.png"
                    alt="imagen de Mitchel"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

CSS:
    .events {
      padding: 100px 0 120px 80px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: start;
      justify-content: space-between;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    
    .events__content {
      flex-basis: 580px;
    }
    
    .events__heading {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: 500;
      line-height: 30px;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .events__title {
      font-size: 44px;
      font-weight: 500;
      line-height: 52px;
      margin: 32px 0 0;
    }
    
    .events__info-section {
      margin-top: 32px;
    }
    
    .event-info__item {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: 4px;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    .event-info__icon {
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      margin-right: 12px;
      width: 24px;
      height: 24px;
    }
    
    .event-info__text {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: 500;
      line-height: 30px;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .events__description {
      margin: 40px 0 60px;
    }
    
    .events__more {
      color: #2f80ed;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .events__cover {
      flex-grow: 1;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      flex-basis: 780px;
      max-width: 780px;
      /*position: relative;*/
    }
    
    .events__image {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    .person {
      position: relative;
      /*z-index: 1;*/
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 10px;
    }
    
    .person_name_feynman {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      right: 319px;
    }
    
    .person_name_burbidge {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 96px;
      left: 125px;
    }
    
    .person_name_cannon {
      position: absolute;
      top: 18px;
      left: 216px;
    }
    
    .person_name_mitchell {
      position: absolute;
      top: 82px;
      right: 142px;
    }
    
    .person_name_tarter {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 79px;
      left: 159px;
    }
    
    .person__image {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    .person__image_size_l {
      width: 140px;
    }
    
    .person__image_size_m {
      width: 100px;
    }
    
    .person__image_size_s {
      width: 80px;
    }
    
    .person__caption {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 14px;
      margin: 0;
    }

Trate de usar relative y absolute respectivamente con top, bottom, right y left, sin embargo cuando inserto los códigos simplemente las imágenes se apilan de manera vertical y debo distribuirlas de acuerdo al detalle adjunto.
Así debería quedar el ejercicio:

Así es como actualmente queda con mi código actual:


Usamos absolute para indicarle a un elemento que no debe respetar el orden del documento. 
En otras palabras, para que deje de formar parte de la estructura de la página y se posicione tomando como referencia un elemento padre que tenga position:relative.
Si no se lo ponemos a ningún elemento más grande entonces, por defecto, tomará como referencia al body.
Lo que yo haría, sería ponerle position: relative al elemento que contiene todo, en este caso a .events__cover y darle sus medidas para que abarque todo el espacio.
Luego le pondría position: absolute a la imagen de fondo .events__image. Dandole también un z-index: -1 para que quede en por detrás de los retratos.

Con los elementos .person tienes 2 opciones:
Opción 1. Ubicarlos en una grid usando display: grid. Aunque si eliges esta opción te recomiendo aprender bien sobre CSS-Grid. (igualmente dejo unos enlaces a herramientas útiles: Grid Generator, Todas las propiedades de CSS Grid y Apuntes de Fernando sobre CSS Grid)
Opción 2. Ponerle position: absolute a todos los retratos .person y luego posicionarlos usando top y left, o right como hiciste tú.

Aunque en tú código te confundiste un poco y pusiste position: relative a los .person y luego a cada uno le diste el absolute contradiciendote. Pero supongo que por eso estamos aquí, no pasa nada.
Espero que se entienda algo de lo que intento explicar, soy un poco disperso pero espero haber ayudado.

Útimo consejo, por buenas prácticas y semántica de Html: El elemento grande que contiene todo (.event__cover) debería de ser un <ul></ul> y los divs mas pequeños (.person) serían sus <li></li> ya que es una lista de elementos.
Y si quieres ponerle varias clases a un mismo elemento puedes ponerlas todas en el mismo atributo class="" separadas por espacios.
Suerte con tu proyecto.

Esto no es una respuesta. Debes participar más para obtener reputación y poder comentar. Puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [answer] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu respuesta sea marcada como aceptada.

@OCHOA no se si esta bien o mal, pero porque decis que no es una respuesta?

En serio @gbianchi?  Siempre me han dicho que si no se resuelve lo que el OP pregunta no califica como una respuesta sino como un comentario largo, dar buenas practicas y consejos se puede hacer en comentarios. Para saber si está bien o no, se necesita ejemplos del resultado, pero claro, al final ustedes deciden que está bien o no. Si esto responde la pregunta del OP déjelo, total solo hice lo que siempre hago con este tipo de "respuestas".  Haz lo que creas conveniente, puedes dejar este comentario (que no digo que sea malo) o pedir código o lo que sea.

No tengo idea de este tema, asi que no se si resuelve lo que OP pregunta. Pero yo veo un intento honesto de contestar la duda. No me parece un comentario.. Tiene errores? pide aclaraciones... de igual forma, si esta mal, entonces no se debe reportar. Se deben reportar respuestas que no sean respuestas. Aca esta remarcado supuestos errores (no esta en nosotros calificar como correcto e incorrecto) y dando consejos y arreglos... no entiendo en donde no es una respuesta... @OCHOA

y si le falta codigo, sigue siendo una respueta, sin codigo, la calificas como gustes, y luego se piden las aclaraciones que hagan falta...

Osea que ahora valen los intentos de responder?? OK. Yo solo reporté que no es una respuesta, el sistema no me pidió explicación del porque NO la considero respuesta, solo un radio button de no es respuesta y ya. Vuelvo y te repito has lo que gustes, yo reportaré algo y si no te parece haz caso omiso y listo, o es que a todos mis reportes le vas a pedir una explicación que te satisfaga? Yo hace un tiempo respondía a algunos post así y al final terminaban eliminando mis respuestas. Te repito, si mis reportes están mal, deja las "respuestas" y listo.
